# "Abstract" constructor method passed as argument in Golang

Tags: go, inheritance, interface

As someone who is settled in the Python world I recently had to improve the performance of an API. Out of personal interest I wanted to rework the whole thing with Golang.

One part of the implementation consists of converting coordinates into GeoJson geometries and creating a collection from them.

Since some endpoints require different geometries to be created from the same coordinates, I wanted to abstract everything around constructing the geometries away. My approach was to pass a function that returns an instance of an interface to the method which converts the coordinates.

```
// This is what I want to create
type Collection struct {
    Geometries *[]Geometry
}

type Geometry interface {}

type Point struct {
    Coordinates [1][2]float64
}

type Polygon struct {
    Coordinates [1][5][2]float64
}

type GeometryConstructor func(float64, float64) *Geometry

// This is the method to convert 
func DataFrameToCollection(data DataFrame, constructor GeometryConstructor) *Collection {
    geometries := make([]Geometry, data.Len())
    for i := 0; i < data.Len(); i++ {
        geometries[i] = *constructor(data.Lat.ItemAt(i), data.Lng.ItemAt(i))
    }
    return &Collection{
        Geometries: &geometries,
    }
}

// This is a constructor method I want to pass
func PointFromLatLng(lat, lng float64) *Point {
    return &Point{
        Coordinates: [1][2]float64{
            {lng, lat},
        },
    }
}
```

So I could ultimately just plug the appropriate constructor method like this

```
func main() {
    // data := ...
    collection := DataFrameToCollection(&data, PointFromLatLng)
}
```

The problem is that the constructor methods do not return an interface instance.

What is the most Go-idiomatic way to solve this (avoiding if / switch-case statements)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline adapters:

```
    collection := DataFrameToCollection(&data, func(lat,lon float64) Geometry { return PointFromLatLng(lat,lon) } )
```